# Error accessing Sendinblue (Hosting: Pythonanywhere)

Tags: python-3.x, django, pythonanywhere, sendinblue

**¡Hello!**

I have recently deployed a website developed in Django to Pythonanywhere. The web is integrated with Sendinblue, I checked the Whitelisted and saw that the API is allowed for free accounts in Pythonanywhere. I ask for your help because all the API queries give me errors like the one I show you at the end, on the other hand everything works fine outside the hosting. I would appreciate if you could tell me what I should do to access the Sendinblue API. Thank you very much to all. Greetings

*Error:*

```
2021-03-17 11:55:19,469: Retrying (Retry(total=0, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.HTTPSConnection object at 0x7fb4274735d0>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 101] Network is unreachable')': /v3/contacts?limit=5&offset=0
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're not configuring the library that you're using to use the proxy. Check the documentation of the library to see how to configure the use of a proxy. You can find the proxy details here https://help.pythonanywhere.com/pages/403ForbiddenError/